# Redundancy via Foreign Key to allow for simpler common queries?

Tags: sql, database, database-normalization

I am tempted to add a foreign key to a table that wouldn't need it just for the sake of simplifying common queries. Would it be that bad of a thing?

What follows is a simplified example to illustrate what I'm dealing with.

```
CREATE TABLE group
(
    group_id INT AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL,
    group VARCHAR(32) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (group_id),
)

CREATE TABLE item
(
    item_id INT AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL,
    item VARCHAR(32) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (item_id),
    FOREIGN KEY (group_id) REFERENCES group(group_id)
)

CREATE TABLE order
(
    order_id INT AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL,
    order VARCHAR(32) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (order_id),
    FOREIGN KEY (item_id) REFERENCES item(item_id)
-- FOREIGN KEY (group_id) REFERENCES item(group_id) <- not needed,  but...
)
```

This structure is all that is needed from the logical perspective, but I know that there are 2 common pattern of querying the order table:

1. By item_id
2. By group_id

In the second case the query should look something like:

```
with merged as
(
    SELECT *
    FROM item JOIN group
      ON item.group_id = group.group_id
)

SELECT *
FROM order JOIN merged
  ON order.item_id = merged.item_id
WHERE merged.group = 'my_group'
```

If I add the group_id as foreign key in order I am adding some redundancy (wasting some space), but I can drop the need for the user to join twice.

Also, I'm only 80% sure that the db optimizer can ensure the queries would have the same performance (it technically can't have the SAME performance, but it should have a SIMILAR ENOUGH performance).

Comment: Please clarify via edits, not comments.

Answer (score 0):

First, `group` and `order` are keywords in SQL.  That makes them really bad candidates for table names.  One reason I make table names in the plural is because it avoids conflicts with most keywords.

Second, use foreign key relationships to describe the *structure* of the data.  You can add additional indexes for performance.

Third, you need to declare columns to use them in constraints.

You seem to want:

```
CREATE TABLE groups (
    group_id INT AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL,
    group VARCHAR(32) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (group_id)
);

CREATE TABLE items (
    item_id INT AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL,
    item VARCHAR(32) NOT NULL,
    group_id int,
    PRIMARY KEY (item_id),
    FOREIGN KEY (group_id) REFERENCES group(group_id)
)

CREATE TABLE orders (
    order_id INT AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL,
    order VARCHAR(32) NOT NULL,
    item_id INT,
    PRIMARY KEY (order_id),
    FOREIGN KEY (item_id) REFERENCES item (item_id)
);
```

Items are in groups and orders have items.  You have not described any need to have `group_id` in `orders`.  You can look it up through `item_id`.  Don't store redundant information.

Of course, if `order`s could have `group`s separately from the `item`, then an additional `group_id` column would make sense.

Comment: I made a simplified example, you are reading too much into the names order/items/groups (I tried to translate my problem in a less niche area). An item is uniquely identified by the pair 'group_name, item_name' in my 'real world', that's why I need group_id in items. Maybe I should merge groups and items table and make a pair unique constraint on their names, but it seemed more appropriate not to do so.